# Overriding a static<K,V> method

Tags: java, overloading

We have a method to do a diff on two generic objects:

```
    public static <K, V> Diff<K, V> check(K key, V act, V exp) {
        Diff<K, V> d = null;
        System.out.println(act.getClass());
        System.out.println(exp.getClass());
        // null checks
        if (exp == null && act == null) {
            // both null, so no difference
        } else if (exp == null) {
            d = new Diff<>(key, null, act);
        } else if (act == null) {
            d = new Diff<>(key, exp, null);
        } else {
            // compare the entries
            if (!exp.equals(act)) {
                d = new Diff<>(key, exp, act);
            }
        }

        return d;
    }
```

Problem is, for Dates (java.sql.Date) that is, sometimes the date instead of just MM/dd/yyyy may have MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm while the other does not, so it is not treating them as equals.  I want them to be equal if the dates are the same (I don't care about the hours, minutes, seconds).

So I tried to create a new method:

```
    public static <K, V> Diff<K, java.sql.Date> check(K key, java.sql.Date act, java.sql.Date exp) {
        Diff<K, java.sql.Date> d = null;

        // null checks
        if (exp == null && act == null) {
            // both null, so no difference
        } else if (exp == null) {
            d = new Diff<>(key, null, act);
        } else if (act == null) {
            d = new Diff<>(key, exp, null);
        } else {
            // compare the entries
            if (!exp.toString().equals(act.toString())) {
                d = new Diff<K, java.sql.Date>(key, exp, act);
            }
        }

        return d;
    }
```

for some reason it would not let me say public static.  Anyway, this does not give any compiler errors, but when the program, I see the original method is called.  You can see in the original method I am printing the classes and their values are

```
class java.sql.Date
class java.sql.Date
```

so why is my specialized method not being called, and the generic one is being called?

This is the class (part of it):

```
public static class Diff<K, V> {
    private K key;
    private V exp, act;
    ...
    ...
}
```

(I listed the data, there are a lot of other methods for here which I show ...)

Here is the calling function.  There are several rows in the map.  Some are long, some are string, some are sql dates.  Key is always String, but a lot of other places potentially call this too, which may have other data types for the key.

```
public static <K, V> List<Diff<K, V>> MapComparison(Map<K, V> map1, Map<K, V> map2) {
    List<Diff<K, V>> result = new LinkedList<Diff<K, V>>();

    // null checks
    if (map1 == null) {
        map1 = new HashMap<K, V>();
    }
    if (map2 == null) {
        map2 = new HashMap<K, V>();
    }

    HashSet<K> allKeys = new HashSet<K>();
    allKeys.addAll(map1.keySet());
    allKeys.addAll(map2.keySet());

    for (K key : allKeys) {
        V exp = map1.get(key);
        V act = map2.get(key);
        Diff<K, V> d = Diff.check(key, act, exp);
        if (d != null) {
            result.add(d);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

calls MapComparison:

```
public static DiffListMap doComparison(RowList exp, RowList act, String keyName) {
    DiffListMap ret = new DiffListMap();
    DiffList diffs;

    // Loop through each expected row.
    for (Row exp_row : exp) {
        Object key = exp_row.get(keyName);
        diffs = null;
        boolean found = false;
        // Look for the corresponding actual row
        // using the unique key
        for (Row act_row : act) {
            if (act_row.get(keyName).equals(key)) {
                // If the correct one is found, do the comparison
                found = true;
                diffs = new DiffList(MapComparison(exp_row, act_row));
                // remove the row from the actual results.
                act.remove(act_row);
                break;
            }
        }
```

and FYI

```
public static class Row extends HashMap<String, Object> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I do not know how to correctly format it in a reply.  Here is is but unformatted because it never seems to format in a reply:

It was too long.  I will have to post in next comment

Comment: Unrelated: always use meaningful names. What does `check()` mean? Exactly: nothing. And hint: there is no point of even defining that `V` type in your second case. V isn't used, and therefore shouldnt be showing up at all in there!

Comment: public static <K, V> List<Diff<K, V>> MapComparison(Map<K, V> map1, Map<K, V> map2) {
  List<Diff<K, V>> result = new LinkedList<Diff<K, V>>();

  // null checks
  if (map1 == null) {
   map1 = new HashMap<K, V>();
  }
  if (map2 == null) {
   map2 = new HashMap<K, V>();
  }

  HashSet<K> allKeys = new HashSet<K>();
  allKeys.addAll(map1.keySet());
  allKeys.addAll(map2.keySet());

  for (K key : allKeys) {
   V exp = map1.get(key);
   V act = map2.get(key);
   Diff<K, V> d = Diff.check(key, act, exp);
   if (d != null) {
    result.add(d);
   }
  }
  return result;
 }

Comment: Dont put more information into comments. Edit your question, and format the code there ... as you did format all the other code you have in your question!

Comment: Hi Ghost Cat.  This is someone else's code I am maintaining, so I did not originally name it.

Comment: Hi Ghost Cat.  I guess I didn't realize you could edit the original.  I now have, and have added it there.

Comment: OK.  It is above.  I always have to check to see whether there is any confidential stuff in the code, but I do not see any.  I will list only the relative part

Comment: I am defining it right underneath (in the same class).

Comment: It does not make sense to talk about overriding a static method; only virtual methods can be overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static <K, V> List<Diff<K, V>> MapComparison(Map<K, V> map1, Map<K, V> map2) {
    // ...
    V exp = map1.get(key);
    V act = map2.get(key);
    Diff<K, V> d = Diff.check(key, act, exp);
    // ...
```

Call sites are bound at *compile time*.  The compiler will never bind this invocation of `Diff.check` to your new overload, because it doesn't know nor care that `V` might be bound to `java.sql.Date` at runtime.  It only knows that `K` and `V` are some types derived from `Object`, so it binds to the only method it can: `Diff<K, V> check(K, V, V)`.

Comment: do you think in the original then, instead of if (!exp.equals(act)) I could put if !(exp.toString().equals(act.toString())?  For java.sql.Date that would print just yyyy-mm-dd.  But it might screw up for other data types?

Comment: I would not, because the default `toString()` implementation includes the identity hash code.  There is no rule that two equivalent objects must also be equal by `toString()`.  More importantly, there is no rule that objects that are equal by `toString()` are actually equivalent.